# Running Nginx with a database-backed config file

Tags: python, sql, configuration, nginx, fuse

I know there exists a plugin for nginx to load the config through perl. I was wondering, does anyone have any experience doing this without using a plugin? Possibly a fuse-backed Python script that queries a DB?

I would really like to not use the perl plugin, as it doesn't seem that stable.

Comment: What's problem with `bash` run script + simple db-client (aka pgsql)?

Comment: VBart, I'm sorry but I'm not really sure what you mean. Do you have a doc or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any working solution to solve your task, a quick google search doesn't give any useful information either (it doesn't look like HttpPerlModule could help with DB stored configuration).

It sounds like it's a good task to develop and contribute to Nginx project !

Comment: Are there any evolutions about this matter? I am thinking about some key-value database to store the nginx.conf ... and where the deamon runs, it would load it from the database, not from file